# Forio Contour dynamic json arrays

Tags: json, forio-contour

Can I use data elements inside the JSON file for the x,y values? Here's my JSON file and I want to use reading_bs as x value and reading_date as y value.

```
[
    {
        "id": 76,
        "user_id": 6,
        "reading_date": "2016-02-23",
        "reading_bs": 2,
        "fasting": true,
        "reading_notes": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": 77,
        "user_id": 6,
        "reading_date": "2016-02-24",
        "reading_bs": 2,
        "fasting": true,
        "reading_notes": "test2"
    },
    {
        "id": 78,
        "user_id": 6,
        "reading_date": "2016-02-25",
        "reading_bs": 2,
        "fasting": true,
        "reading_notes": "test3"
    }
]
```

The other values are used elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `map` the array to include x ands y, after that you can include any other properties in the data set but there no way to specify which fields to take as x and y:

```
data = data.map(function (item) { 
  item.x = item.reading_bs; 
  item.y = item.reading_date; 
  return item;
});
```

Comment: So, this won't work? I'm unclear about your comment on x and y specification. Doesn't the mapping do that?

Comment: I got it to work on single line chart. Does the JSON file need to be devoid of quotes to work or is that just a JSFiddle thing?

Comment: Additionally, can the y axis be dates? If so, how would that work?